# What Layer does a Query Builder belong in?

Tags: design-patterns, php, object-oriented-design

In my project I have specified 5 sublayers for my DBAL:

1. Database Layer ( the database itself)
2. Database Connection Layer ( \PDO and a class that handles the database connections)
3. Database Request Layer( classes that actually query the database )
4. Database Model Layer ( All classes that represent 1 Database table each and a Factory class that gives easy access to all Model class)
5. Model Layer ( classes that combines several Database Model class t make them work together )

Now I have set the restriction that each layer SHOULD only have access to classes of its own layer or classes directly below (Layer 4 MAY access Layer 4 and 3 but MUST NOT access Layer 5 and SHOULD NOT access layers 1 and 2).
But when it comes to a Query Builder ( I've decided to use https://github.com/nilportugues/php-sql-query-builder as it does not require a database connection) I wonder what layer this should be assigned to and where I should use it.

Clearly the resulting query should be passed to Layer 3, so the Query Builder should be either 3 or 4, but then in most cases I seem to more likely need to build a query in layer 5 when I want to create some Layer 4 objects.

Currently my code that uses the Query Builder looks like this (in Layer 5):

```
$builder = $this->entityFactory->getDbRequest()->getQueryBuilder();
// build the $query
$entity = $this->entityFactory->makeEntityByQuery( Entityname::class, $query);
```

So currently I located the QueryBuilder in Layer 3 but that forces me access Layer 3 from Layer 5 which I'd like to avoid. I could move it to layer 4 but then I'd either have to make it a dependency for most Classes of the Model Layer or make it accessible directly from that EntityFactory. But then again the EntityFactory would have 2 responsibilities, which violates SRP.

In which layer do you or would you use the Query Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It feels like Layer 3, the Database Request layer needs this. First, to be honest, the layering could use fixing. If you have "layers" and the question "which layer does this go in?" is not easily answered then you either don't have enough layers, or don't have the *right* layers.

What you have:

1. Database layer
2. Database connection layer
3. Database Request Layer
4. **(this is your problem)** Database Model Layer
5. **(and so is this)** Model Layer

Layer 3, the Database Request Layer is where your Query Builder belongs. Nothing outside of that layer should be doing ad hoc queries. Really, Layer 3 is more commonly referred to as the Data Access Layer (DAL) or Repository Layer. This is the layer that knows about the database. It should even know about the factories required to generated your entity objects.

Think of the DAL or Repository as a coordinating layer between two sub layers: The Database Request and Entity Factory layers.

What you really need:

```
         +----------+
         | Database |
         +----------+
              /\
              ||
              ||
              \/
+----------------------------+    +---------------+    +----------------+    +--------+
| Database Request (Gateway) |    | Query Builder |    | Entity Factory |    | Entity |
+----------------------------+    +---------------+    +----------------+    +--------+
              /\                      /\                       /\                /\
              ||                      ||                       ||                ||
              ||                      ||                       ||                ||
              ||                      ||      ++===============++                ||
              ||                      ||      ||                                 ||
              ||                      ||      ||                                 ||
              ||                      \/      \/                                 ||
              ||                    +------------+                               ||
              ++==================> | Repository | <=============================++
                                    +------------+
                                          /\
                                          ||
                                          ||
                                          \/
                                 +------------------+
                                 | Your Application |
                                 +------------------+
```

Your entity classes should have absolutely no knowledge about persistence. It's the Repository/DAL that coordinates between multiple layers underneath - including your query builder.

Nothing outside the Repository/DAL should have *anything* to do with the query builder. This is a utility for making the construction of SQL queries easier. Instead, you can provide a Data Transfer Object (DTO) that will contain all the possible criteria values if you need to perform a search. The Repository/DAL should have a method that accepts this criteria DTO as an argument, and then uses the DTO to build a query using the Query Builder.

From that, something else has to translate the query builder object into a request to the database. You can create another class called a Query Executor which translates the Query Builder and creates a DB request, or just pass the query builder directly to the DB request object. Yeah you "break the separation of layers" but how much coupling have you *really* introduced? It's up to you.

**Once your application reaches the complexity where you have a question like this, you need to invest your time in learning and configuring a good Object Relational Mapper (ORM).**

---

> So I Inject those repository classes to my Application classes?

Yes, but generally only your controllers and service classes will need access to repository objects.

> Are those repository classes manually created in the controller (or the DI-Container respectively)?

A little be "Yes" and a little bit "No".

If you use Dependency Injection then the DI container or a factory object that churns out controllers will instantiate the repository.

If you introduce interfaces for your repository, you can have both:

```
interface IFooRepository
{
    public function find($id);
}

class FooRepository implements IFooRepository
{

}

class FoosController
{
    public function __construct(IFooRepository $repository = null) {
        if (!isset($repository)) {
            $repository = new FooRepository();
        }

        $this->repository = $repository;
    }
}
```

The constructor for the controller accepts an `IFooRepository` as an argument. If `null` it defaults to the `FooRepository` concrete implementation. Now, you can actually unit test your controllers by providing a mock or stub of the `IFooRepository` interface.

Comment: So basically for every table in the database there should be 

( 1. )an entity class that models the table data as a value object

( 2.) a repository class that is responsible for all types of interactions with the database table and returns an entity object when data is requested and takes a modified entity object when data should be stored to the database

?

Comment: @Tekay37: Yup. You got it. :)

Comment: Though a repository doesn't have to be concerned with one table. It can be concerned with a group of closely related tables.

Comment: Ok, that helped me a lot. Thanks so far. I have two additional questions though:
(1) So I Inject those repository classes to my Application classes?
(2) Are those repository classes manually created in the controller (or the DI-Container respectively)?

Comment: @Tekay37: I updated my answer to address your questions.

Comment: This answer could be improved by converting the ASCII art to an MS Paint drawing, preferably with hand-drawn red circles for emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

If the query builder is in L3 and accessed from L5, you could add a thin wrapper for the query builder in L4 so that you access the L4 wrapper from L5, and the L4 wrapper accesses L3. Except, L4 is for classes that represent a single table, so a wrapper for a query builder doens't quite seem to fit here...

So, maybe not everything fits neatly in these layers, but maybe that's OK some of the time. Maybe it's also a problem of having layers arranged in a strict hierarchy, when the relationship between them is a bit more complex.

Maybe you're being *too* restrictive in how you think about the structure of your code?

Comment: I was actually thinking about adding an optional layer between L3 and L4 that would contain the queryBuilder and a wrapper class that manages it.

Comment: Basically what you need is a "repository" or data access object that represents the actions that can be performed on the entire data set.